# emulator is throwing error

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I rum the emulator then it is throwing  error.I am not getting that why it is throwing error.[image]

this is the screen shot of my error which is thrown by emulator during running the programme .
It is showing visual studio just -in time debugger error .

Answer (score 0):

just delete the old emulator and create a new emulator it works fine it will be in window-AVDManager